# Tar Error [can not open: not a directory]

Tags: tar

I have made some archive file with the tar gnome GUI on Ubuntu but when I try to extract them

```
tar zxvf archive_name
```

I get following error

```
Cannot open: Not a directory
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try extracting the archive in an empty directory; any existing files/directories in the extract target usually cause problems if names overlap.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue (for each file within an archive) and I solved it by appending ".tar.gz" to the archive filename as I'd managed to download a PECL package without a file extension:

```
mv pecl_http pecl_http.tar.gz
```

I was then able to issue the following command to extract the contents of the archive:

```
tar -xzf pecl_http.tar.gz
```

Comment: Had similar issue with regular tar (not gz). After renaming, I could extract with `tar -xvf` without getting "Tar Error [can not open: not a directory]"

Answer (score 1):

You probably might already have a file with the same name that the tar is extracting a directory.
Try to tar in different location.

`tar zxvf tar_name.tgz --one-top-level=new_directory_name`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tar -zxvf archive_name` instead. I believe that the command format has changed, and it now requires the z (unzip) x (extract) v (verbose) f (filename...) parts as switches instead of plain text. The error comes from tar trying to do something to the file zxvf, which of course does not exist.